# Continuity of probability measure from below - proof

Tags: measure-theory

Just looked at a result saying that for a probablity measure $\mu$ defined on $Q$, and for a monotone increasing sequence $\lbrace E_n \rbrace $: $E_n \subset E_{n+1}$, $E_n \in Q$,

(1) $\lim\limits_{n}\mu(E_n)=\mu(\lim\limits_{n}E_n)$.

By another elementary result, one also has that $\mu(E_n) \leq \mu(E_{n+1})$ (have been shown prior to above on occasions). In showing (1), none seem to employ the latter, for I thought it was not much more to say (and once the inequalities been established)  than $E=\lim\limits_{n}E_n$ exists and that $\lbrace \mu(E_n) \rbrace$ is an increasing sequence of real numbers bounded by $\mu(E)$, so by the "monotone convergence theorem for real numbers" it converges to $\mu(E)$. Am I missing some?

Edit: As pointed out by saz in the comments, $\mu(E_n)$ is bounded by $\mu(E)$, but we don't know that $\mu(E)=\text{sup} \lbrace \mu(E_n): n=1,2,3... \rbrace$. All in all, the suggestion fails.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "monotone convergence theorem for real numbers"...?

Comment: @saz I think the OP is referring to the theorem that states that a bounded monotonic increasing sequence of real numbers converges to the supremum of the sequence.

Comment: (a_k) is an increasing sequence of real numbers and a=sup(a_k: k=1,2...) then a_k has limit a

Comment: How do you know that the limit $a:= \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(E_n)$ equals $\mu(E)$? (This does not immediately follow from the fact that $\mu(E_n)$ is bounded by $\mu(E)$.)

Comment: @kobe that is correct

Comment: The claim here was that $\mu(E)=sup \lbrace \mu(E_n) : n=1,2... \rbrace$.

Comment: @ saz so this last part is what you're after? .... yeah, how do I know that...

Comment: @undefined Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: Yeah, you're totally correct. Thanks